# Count how many times a JButton is pressed?

Tags: java, user-interface, button, jbutton

In the action performed code in a JAVA GUI, how would I count how many times a button is pressed, and do something different for each press of the button?

```
  private class Listener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
     {

       HOW WOULD I COUNT HOW MANY TIMES THIS BUTTON HAS BEEN PRESSED?

     }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class variable and then increment the variable in the method.

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener   
{      
    private int clicked;

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
         clicked++
    }
}
```

You can then create a method to access the variable.

Comment: Thanks mate! I quickly realized this was a stupid question after I asked it.  I should have spent some more time thinking about it.  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a field in the Listener class and increment it every time the button is pressed and then have a switch to select the action to perform depending on the value of your variable.

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener   
{      
    private int clicks;

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        clicks++;
        switch (clicks){
            case '1':
                // Do operation 1
                break;
            case '2':
                // Do operation 2
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i assume you mean a field in the class, not a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Too much programming in C for the past 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

### You have declared clicks as int, therefore, case statement needs int value not the char.

**Corrected version:**

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener   
{      
    private int clicks;

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        clicks++;
        switch (clicks){
            case 1:
                // Do operation 1
                break;
            case 2:
                // Do operation 2
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `e.getClickCount` in your MouseEvent