# Find out how many times button is clicked

Tags: java, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count how many times a JButton is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602463/count-how-many-times-a-jbutton-is-pressed)

Suppose i have a button like

```
JButton button1=new JButton();
```

and i have a `int count=0`

what is the code to find how many times the button is clicked??
(it is something similar to mouseup event in C# but i want it in java)
Thankyou

Comment: Just increment count variable inside click event of JButton? and don't declare count as local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button1.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
      count += 1;
   }

});
```

Where `count` has to be an Instance Variable and is declared just right after your class.

Comment: `count` must be member of top-class

Comment: count variable has to be an instance variable.

Comment: It is the same thing. I mean - add this information to your anser.

Comment: Thanks for informing sir Dmitry.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mouse listener to the button which increments the counter.

```
button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Implement action listener for button1.
2. Increment the count (Instance variable) by one.
3. Then You can get the click count.

> ```
> int count = 0; // Instance variable
> button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>             public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>                count++;
>                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Clicked count is : " + count);
>             }
>         });
> ```

Comment: @Dmitry Zaitsevl See my edit..

Comment: Still wrong. `count` must be an instance variable.

Comment: @Dmitry Zaitsevl Is there any Changes needed?